# In SQL, How to select not duplicate values?

Tags: php, sql

```
$country = $row['COUNTRY'];
```

COUNTRY

```
Singapore
Japan
China
China
Singapore
Japan
China
Malaysia
Malaysia
South Korea
Malaysia
```

All records contains duplicate values except South Korea. I want to select South Korea using variable. without using Id.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: It is not clear what you want here. Do you want a query that only selects non-duplicated countries or to process an array of countries looking for the ones that are not duplicated?

Comment: I use xampp database bro

Comment: yes a query that select not duplicate values

Comment: use `DISTINCT` if you wish to only see each available name exactly once: `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable.`

Comment: XAMPP is **not** a database. Did you mean MariaDB? MySQL?

Comment: yes MariaDB. And i use xampp as application

Answer (score 1):

Using a count and `having` you can get only those rows that occur once i.e. the counties that are not duplicated

```
SELECT country,  count(country) as c_count
FROM   country_table
GROUP BY country
HAVING c_count = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the name of the country, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT country
FROM country_table
GROUP BY country
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

If you have a unique id on each row (i.e. a primary key) and a lot of data, you might find that this is faster:

```
select ct.country
from country_table ct
where not exists (select 1
                  from country_table ct2
                  where ct2.country = ct.country and ct2.id <> ct.id
                 );
```